# Why eng.traineddata file size is decrease when I increased the number of digits in tesseract ?

Tags: java, android

I want to recognize handwritten digits in android and I am going to trained to tesseract but when I increase the size of sample character then size of traineddata file is decrease.I don't know why Plz help me?